# Chaining Facebook Promises ngCordova

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm currently trying to do multiple API Calls to Facebook.

**My Setup is the Ionic Framework (Cordova), ngCordova and the Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin (all master Versions).**

In this Example I'm trying to gather FB Events created by different Pages, in an attempt to display them all later in my View. Basically I'm making three FB API Calls, merging the Response and assigning it to a scope Variable.

```
var clubs = ["page1" , "page2", "page3" ];
    angular.forEach(clubs, function(value, key) {
      promises.push($cordovaFacebook.api(value+"/events?fields=cover,name,owner"));
    });
    return $q.all(promises);
  })
  .then(function (success){
    console.log(success);}); '
```

This doesn't work however. I don't get any Console Output and the "then" Function with the Success Handler is never reached, and I can't seem to figure out why. Any Ideas would be appreciated! Besides, would it be possible to further optimise performance by somehow running these calls parallel?

Comment: What actual number of pages do you intend to request the data for? Is three a fixed number, or will it eventually be a couple of pages, or dozens or more? If the number isn’t too large, it might be better to query that data in a single API request (easier to handle, plus less HTTP requests equals less waiting time for the user).

Comment: It will be more than just three. This was just me trying it out. The idea is to load a list of Pages depending on the Users location and then show all the Events that local Pages around the User have created.